# How to protect MSI installer digital signature from tampering

Tags: security, windows-installer, portable-executable, cryptoapi

My Windows MSI installer has a digital signature signed with a valid code signing certificate.
To validate incoming update installer, I use WinVerifyTrust to verify the file trust and also checked if signer exactly match my organization's name, say ABC, Inc. for example.
But the file is being reported that it might be compromised by certificate chain attack.
The hacker can use the same signer's name under different certificate chain path. So, what can I do to prevent such attack? Validate each signer's name until Root CA, or any other efficient method to prevent?
I can't figure it out for a while and need some experts to help out some advice.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to change the certificate chain, such as rotating an expired root certificate or moving to another CA. As for the certificate chain attack, to get a legitimate signing key with a specific CN from a CA you need to prove that you are the entity with that CN. This is usually enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't trust the CAs installed in Windows (even though generally you can because that is ~everybody's security boundary), you can always set up your own CA and add a second signature to your MSI that's signed with a certificate issued by that CA. Your updater can check that, while for regular MSI execution, Windows will be content with the regular certificate. You'll have the overhead of running your own CA though, including the security requirements that come from dealing with some customers.